# Is There a Connection Between an Infinitude of Mersenne Primes and the Divergence of the Harmonic Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, mersenne-numbers

I recently came across

https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/

which asserts that there likely exists an infinite number of even perfect numbers because of the divergence of the harmonic series.

Can somebody explain such a connection of the harmonic series to the question of the infinitude of Mersenne primes?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but I wonder if the author meant to say [the prime harmonic series](https://planetmath.org/primeharmonicseries).

Comment: @saulspatz That now gives a logical connection. Thank you.

Comment: I vaguely remember that when I was young, I played around with the odd perfect number problem, and I thought that if I could show that the prime harmonic series converges, I could show that there is no odd perfect number.  Of course, I later found out that the series diverges.  I'll try to remember what connection I had in mind, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: @saulpatz Thank you again.If you think of it, I'd like to know what it was.

Comment: The sum of the reciprocals of the twin primes connverges, although the  conjecture is that there are infinitely many. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem